# Storage on Windows Azure and VPS bandwith

Tags: php, azure-storage

I'm planning to buy a VPS with monthly transfer of 4 TB.
I have a website that uses video content and currently uses Vimeo, but we encountered a problem with video upload where Vimeo must reencode the video and that takes some time. So what we are planning to do is to upload file first to our server so the users can access it right away, then upload it to Vimeo from the server in the background, and in a cron job later at the end of the day replace file on our server with Vimeo file URL and delete the file.

Since we have a limit on bandwidth, if we keep the file on our server, everytime it is streamed our bandwidth is deducted from, correct?
To overcome this, we are discussing uploading the video to Windows Azure storage instead of our server.

The question is, if the video uses the storage URL from Azure, does this consume our bandwidth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are absolutely right. If your assets are stored in Azure Storage, even you perform your assets via your Azure Web Apps application, the data out is count in Azure Storage.

I have a simple test for this, I store a video in Azure Storage, and play it via HTML in Azure Web Apps leveraging the following code:

```
<video style="height:640px;widht:960px" controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
      <source src="<video in Azure Storage>" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

And we can find the `data out` metrics in the Azure portal:

- Data Out metric of Azure Storage
  [image]
- Data Out metric of Azure Web Apps
  [image]